# Why Active Application becoming RED color when processing?

Tags: android

I have done one program that allow user can listen to the music via WebView.
I wonder why my program become to RED color when it's running, please see the image.

I have done a mistake in coding?

[image]

Comment: I think the program turns red because it's just embarrassed about the whole Justin Bieber thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it might be related to "Strict Mode":

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html